# Firefox hangs in an infinite loop and ignores css on window.print()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

On a homepage i try to print a popup.
On Chrome it works, but in firefox it doesn't work, somehow it ignores the css file.

In Firefox the window is loading something, but i don't know what it is , because i cannot open firebug.
The formatting HTML looks right, but the printer doesn't get the css information.
So i though it could be, because he loads something.

`HTML+JS` code (fiddle doesn't allow `document.write`):

http://pastebin.com/QXASsTXg

`popup.css`:

http://pastebin.com/HM6JEMnX

Sorry for pastebin, but the code is to large for stackoverflow.

`Javascript Code`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.depart span').click(function(){

        //close all popups
        $('.popup').hide();

        //open current popup
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    });

    $('.close').click(function(){
    // close all popups    
        $('.popup').slideUp();

    });

    $('span.printbutton').click(function(){
    printPopup($(this));
    });
});
function printPopup(data){
    var popup = data.parent().parent().parent('div.popup');
    mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=600,width=420');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Popup</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="popup.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="popup.css" type="text/css" />');

    mywindow.document.write('</head>')
    mywindow.document.write('<body class="popupwindow">')
    mywindow.document.write('<div class="popup">')

    mywindow.document.write(popup.html());
    mywindow.document.write('</div>')

    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
//  mywindow.location.reload();
    mywindow.focus();
    mywindow.print();
    setTimeout('mywindow.close();', 5000);

    return true;
}
```

Hope someone could help.

Edit: A new hint found, when popup is loading the loop, i have to press the ESC-Key to cancel the loop, then i can press STRG+P and it works fine. 
Where could be the error?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it myself, if someone else has the same Problem, this is the solution:
After your last

```
mywindow.document.write('</html>');
```

you need this line for Firefox:

```
mywindow.document.close();
```

After that line Firefox stops waiting for other content and i can print the popup without problems.
Somehow Chrome is ignoring the missing line and i works fine, but firefox need it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Throurg Jquery Pull Css from That Printout Page  
INSTEAD OF :
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="popup.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="popup.css" type="text/css" />');

    USE : $("#printoutpage").css();

See If It Works
```

Comment: The popup looks right, also the css information.
The only Problem is, that the printer doesn't get the information.

Comment: Awwesssome @demonking

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the absolute path to the css file:

```
mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="\path\to\css\popup.css" type="text/css" />');
mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="\path\to\css\popup.css" type="text/css" />');
```

Comment: The Popup works great, but the printer doesn't receive the css information.

Comment: Have you tested this though? Your browser probably can't find the path to the css file... You should set an absolute path and try to print again...

Comment: Yes, i have tested it, but it doesn't works.
The Printer only get the information without css

Comment: You state the window is loading something, but it hangs... It sounds like the browser is trying to request something that it can't find. If you can't get firebug to work, then try some other sniffer (fiddler for instance) to see the request that is hanging the browser...

Comment: The problem is, that fiddle say's that they don't support document.write ;/
i have also tested livehtpp header and nothing was send, everything hat 200 GET

Comment: Use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), `JsFiddle` is for creating test code, not for sniffing traffic.